# Can't get token - using async storage method - react native(Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a feedback form and I'm having trouble getting token from the server after I logged into a random user account. This is my code:

getToken function:

```
getToken = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
      this.setState({ userToken: value });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
    }
};
```

submit function:

```
postFeedback(userToken, title, content, to_id, category) {
    fetch(
      "https://deployattendancemanagement.herokuapp.com/api/feedback/send",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token: userToken,
          title: title,
          content: content,
          to_id: to_id,
          category: category
        })
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => {
        if (typeof res.result != "success") {
          console.log(res.message);
          Alert.alert(
            "Oops !",
            "Something went wrong",
            [
              {
                text: "OK",
                onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
                style: "cancel"
              }
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          );
        } else {
          console.log("success");
          Alert.alert(
            "Yay !",
            "Something went right",
            [
              {
                text: "OK",
                onPress: () => console.log("Send feedback"),
                style: "cancel"
              }
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          );
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Button:

```
<Button
   full
   onPress={() =>
     this.postFeedback(
       this.state.userToken,
       this.state.title,
       this.state.content,
       this.state.to_id,
       this.state.category
     )
   }
>
  <Text>SUBMIT</Text>
</Button>
```

But after I pressed the button, the title and content were not sent and it gives me this error: No Token Provided. Please help, I'm very new at react-native programming.

Comment: I also see you are using both promises and async awaits syntax. I suggest to stick to one of them as that approach might just clear up some things

Answer (score 0):

You have not called `getToken()` function in your code. That would be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are not saving the token. You need to save it before you can retrieve it. It would be helpful if you could share the code where you receive the token but here's the general syntax of saving something to AsyncStorage. Also make sure you call the `getToken()` function.

```
saveToken = async () => {
 let token = 'something';
 await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', token); 
};
```